# Why was I not notified of this answer?

Tags: bug

[Here is an answer to my question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/133592/77533).

I did not get a notification in my inbox for it.

Why?

Comment: Just curious: do you see the answer on this page: https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox ?

Comment: @Glorfindel No.